# Correct way to implement piecewise function in pandas / numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I need to create a function to pass to `curve_fit`.  In my case, the function is best defined as a piecewise function.

I know that the following doesn't work, but I'm showing it since it makes the intent of the function clear:

```
def model_a(X, x1, x2, m1, b1, m2, b2):
    '''f(x) has form m1*x + b below x1, m2*x + b2 above x2, and is
    a cubic spline between those two points.'''
    y1 = m1 * X + b1
    y2 = m2 * X + b2
    if X <= x1:
        return y1    # function is linear below x1
    if X >= x2:
        return y2    # function is linear above x2
    # use a cubic spline to interpolate between lower
    # and upper line segment
    a, b, c, d = fit_cubic(x1, y1, x2, y2, m1, m2)
    return cubic(X, a, b, c, d)
```

The problem, of course, is that X is a pandas Series, and the form `(X <= x1)` evaluates to a series of booleans, so this fails with the message "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous."

It appears that [`np.piecewise()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html) is designed for exactly this situation: "Wherever condlist[i] is True, funclist[i](x) is used as the output value."  So I tried this:

```
def model_b(X, x1, x2, m1, b1, m2, b2):
    def lo(x):
        return m1 * x + b1
    def hi(x):
        return m2 * x + b2
    def mid(x):
        y1 = m1 * x + b1
        y2 = m2 * x + b2
        a, b, c, d = fit_cubic(x1, y1, x2, y2, m1, m2)
        return a * x * x * x + b * x * x + c * x + d

    return np.piecewise(X, [X<=x1, X>=x2], [lo, hi, mid])
```

But this fails at this call:

```
return np.piecewise(X, [X<=x1, X>=x2], [lo, hi, mid])
```

with the message "IndexError: too many indices for array".  I'm inclined to think it's objecting to the fact that there are two elements in *condlist* and three elements in *funclist*, but the docs specifically state that the extra element in *funclist* is treated as the default.

Any guidance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [piece of code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L531) in NumPy's definition of `np.piecewise` is `list`/`ndarray`-centric:

```
# undocumented: single condition is promoted to a list of one condition
if isscalar(condlist) or (
        not isinstance(condlist[0], (list, ndarray)) and x.ndim != 0):
    condlist = [condlist]
```

Thus, if `X` is a Series, then `condlist = [X<=x1, X>=x2]` is a list of two `Series`. 
Since `condlist[0]` is neither a `list` nor an `ndarray`, `condlist` is "promoted" to a list of one condition:

```
condlist = [condlist]
```

Since this is not what we want to happen, we need to make `condlist` a list of NumPy arrays before passing it to `np.piecewise`:

```
X = X.values
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def model_b(X, x1, x2, m1, b1, m2, b2):
    def lo(x):
        return m1 * x + b1
    def hi(x):
        return m2 * x + b2
    def mid(x):
        y1 = m1 * x + b1
        y2 = m2 * x + b2
        # a, b, c, d = fit_cubic(x1, y1, x2, y2, m1, m2)
        a, b, c, d = 1, 2, 3, 4
        return a * x * x * x + b * x * x + c * x + d
    X = X.values
    return np.piecewise(X, [X<=x1, X>=x2], [lo, hi, mid])

X = pd.Series(np.linspace(0, 100, 100))
x1, x2, m1, b1, m2, b2 = 30, 60, 10, 5, -20, 30
f = model_b(X, x1, x2, m1, b1, m2, b2)
```